# Using functions on each file in list of files

Tags: r

I need to write a function which will clear the NA values out of several hundred dataframes, then return a list with the number of complete rows in each dataframe.

I have the following so far:

```
complete_rows <- function(directory, id=1:332){

    # reads directory of files

    file_list <- list.files(path = directory)

    
   # subsets the files the id argument calls for

    id_files <- file_list[id]


    # returns list of files, na rows stripped

    nolist <- lapply(id_files, na.omit)


    # returns list of number of rows in each nolist file

    numlist <- lapply(nolist, nrow)


    #returns id number binded to numlist, 

    cbind(id, numlist)

    }
```

The file_list and id_files steps work correctly. Things seem to not work on the nolist and numlist stages. When I try to access one of the dataframes in nolist;

```
 01 <- nolist[1]
```

I get the following error: "Error in 1 <- nolist[1] : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment"

As I understand it, lapply takes a list (here, id_files or nolist), and a function (na.omit or nrow), applies the function to each dataframe in the list, then returns the modified dataframes in a list. But I can't tell if the nolist step is working and don't know how to access the dataframes within it, and the numlist step just returns a list of NULL values.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not how you use `lapply`. The second argument should be a _function_, not a _call_. The difference is that a call has `()` after it. You need to pass the bare function name, like `lapply(id_files, na.omit)` and `lapply(nolist, nrow)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `01 <- nolist[1]` is not valid in R. You cannot start a variable name with a number. So `01` is invalid to assign to.

For example,

```r
> 01 <- 5
Error in 1 <- 5 : invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment
```

Try something like `df01 <- nolist[1]`. In your `lapply` statements, also remove the `()` from the functions (e.g., `lapply(nolist, nrow)`.

Comment: I've removed the brackets in the lapply uses but I'm still not getting what I want. numlist is still just giving me the list of csv file names, and attempting to use lapply(numlist, na.omit) just gets a list full of NULL values.

Comment: Ah. Right. At no point are you actually importing data. What is the file type? Your file_list simply lists the files. You need to iterate over that with some type read function, like read.csv for example.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew the error was in that section, just didn't know what was going wrong. The function works as intended now. 

Much appreciated!